# R Merge By adding rows

Tags: r, merge, dplyr

I have 2 data sets, 1 with information about travels, and the other one containing the cost per travel depending on where I'm leaving from. I need to get the total cost of the travel and it's easy to do with a merge by where I'm leaving from, but when I do this it adds 1,500 rows to my 100,000 row dataset.. 
Anyone knows why is this happening? The biggest dataset is 100,000 rows, the other one is about 10,000

**EDIT**
This is a subset of df1

```
x Poste       Locat  V3
1 905916      Mixco 0.3
2 905818      Mixco 0.6
3 905818      Mixco 0.6
4 905338 Castellana 0.5
5 904876      Mixco 0.3
```

This is a subset of df2

```
x  Vehiculo  Poste
1  Camion    340592
2  Camion    262776
3  Camion    340622
4  Camion    243254
5  Camion    258505
```

I need to merge both datasets using "Poste", as I will get the cost based on both "Locat"(location) and "Vehiculo"(vehicle) from another dataset.

```
sol <- merge(sol, df[,c(5,16)], by="Poste")
```

Comment: Please show the code you used and the output you got from it.

Comment: You have multiple matches with your join criteria.

Comment: Please use a minimal reproducible example to explain your problem.

Comment: Look at the documentation `?merge` to work out whether you need `all.x` and/or `all.y` equal to `TRUE`. At the moment it sounds like a full join.

Comment: Clearly you have duplicate `Poste` values in `df1` - rows 2 and 3 are the same. If there are duplicate values in `df2` then each pair will match and you will get more rows of data. Try `any(duplicated(df2$Poste))` to see.